# python relative imports randomly fail

Tags: python, relative-path

beside main.py, i have a folder containing more .py files. I want to import those files in main.py, and also in others of those files. 
In main.py

```
from folder import file1, file2
```

so far works (though it did fail once iirc). 
in the other files neither of

```
from . import file3
import file3
from folder import file3
```

work consistently. So far i tried:

```
import folder #in main.py or the other files

import sys
sys.path.append("/folder") #in main.py
```

and adding an **init**.py (obviously with underscores, not bold) that should be unnecessary in python3 and a few other things i forgot. Whenever i changed anything, the import would usually work once or twice, and then again fail with

```
builtins.SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

most things I tried, I read about in similar questions on SO, so yes, I’m aware of them. As I said, none of it worked. 
One thing I haven’t tried (although it might work) is creating a linked-list directory layout (because I’d like to avoid

```
from folder.folder.folder.folder.folder.folder.folder.folder.folder import file
```

also, I’m confident but not absolutely sure yet that I’ll never need cross-imports

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, having used other IDEs with other languages, I expected wing to execute main.py when I pressed F5, like those other IDEs did. Wing executed whichever file I had last edited.

So when I edited main.py to make the imports work, they did. Then when the buggy script failed somewhere else and I fixed something, the imports would stop working.

Always adding and deleting a space in main.py before pressing F5 solved that problem (but there’s probably a more elegant solution)